# write model of Tbox using Jena API

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I'm using Jena API to add a TBox model into an ABox model. The TBox file contains Classes, ObjectProperties, DatatypeProperties. The ABox has individuals. I used `aBoxModel.add(tBoxModel)`, then 
`aBoxModel.write(out)`, which keeps messing up when I use Protégé to open the new file. All the Classes from the TBox showed up in the list of Individuals in Protégé. 
Then I found out the problem occurs by the TBox, not the Abox. And I tried different ways to write it out, which gives me different results. Code as followed:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;

public class TestWriteOwl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OntModel oldModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        RDFDataMgr.read(oldModel, "TBox.owl");  

        FileWriter out;
        try {
            out = new FileWriter("myModel.owl");
            oldModel.write(out,"RDF/XML");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Above is the code with no problem in Protégé, but one little thing: the comments are written in German, and the German letter like ö,ä,ü,ß shows only as question mark "?" in the new file, while they are showed correctly in the old file.
And I can't use the code above because it doesn't help when I try to add the tBox model into another model. So I tried the code below.

```
        OntModel newModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        newModel.add(oldModel);

        FileWriter out;
        try {
            out = new FileWriter("myModel.owl");
            newModel.write(out,"RDF/XML");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this second code is the one that keeps messing up in Protégé. All the Classes showed up in both the list of Individuals and the list of Classes in Protégé, which should've been shown only in Classes. And the German letter problem still exist. 
Then I tried some codes I found on the Internet.

```
        Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner().bindSchema( oldModel );
        OntModelSpec spec = new OntModelSpec( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF );
        spec.setReasoner( reasoner );
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( spec, newModel );

        FileWriter out;
        try {
            out = new FileWriter("myModel.owl");
            m.write(out,"RDF/XML");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the third one has the same problems like the second one.

How can I fix it or is there some methods else I can try?

Comment: without seeing the data before and after you combined both models, impossible to say anything meaningful ...

Comment: regarding German letter, this is most likely an encoding issue, either on file level or in you URIs

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's just in the method `model1.add(model2)`, `model2` must be a `Model`, cannot be an `OntModel`.

Comment: I don't get it. There is neither model1 nor model2 in your code. I also don't see why this should be the solution